# ¿ Por qué si pongo tiempo = i , siendo i un numero no me lo coge en Unity?

Tags: unity

Tengo `tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;` y cuando llega a 0 quiero que según una variable que va sumándose se sustituya , es decir, `i = 2` , cuando tiempo llegue a 0, que `tiempo = 2` , y despues a `tiempo = 3`... debido a que habrá un `i++` , pero si pongo `tiempo = i` o `tiempo = +i` no entiende nada y no me coge la `i`, por que? son `float` los dos.

código:

```
void Update(){

   float tiempo,i=2;
   tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;
   i++;

   if(tiempo == 0)
   tiempo = i;  // Esto no me coge que es i
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente tiempo nunca es 0 porque

```
tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;
```

reduce esa variable por fracciones, usa

```
if(tiempo <= 0)
   tiempo = i;
```

Comment: +1 gracias, era eso

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la respuesta de [user3175146](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66214/por-qu%C3%A9-si-pongo-tiempo-i-siendo-i-un-numero-no-me-lo-coge-en-unity/66241#66217) es parte del problema, quizas uno muy importante, pienso que aun asi esto no hace lo que quiere, y quizas ahora se esta volviendo "loco" sin saber porque no le funciona, o peor aun quizas no sea percatado de que no funciona como usted describe en su pregunta al lio:

---

Primer caso:

```
void Update(){

    float tiempo = 1,i=2; //maracara un error pues no esta asignada asi que le ponemos 1 para hacer el test y que pueda compilar con unity
    tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;
    i++;

    //tiempo nunca sera mayor que dos y de pasar que time en la misma 
    //iterecion deje a tiempo como pide
    //esto solo durara hasta que se
    //vuelva a entrar en el Update pues al ser local la variable se 
    //vuelve a crear con el valor de 1

    Debug.Log("tiempo" + tiempo);

    if(tiempo <= 0)//se añade la correcion de user3175146 muy bien vista
    tiempo = i;  // Esto no me coge que es i
}
```

---

Segundo caso (aunque se mejoren las variables a global):

```
float tiempo;
float i;

void Start(){

   tiempo = 1;
   i=2;
}
void Update(){

    tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;
    i++;

    Debug.Log("tiempo" + tiempo);

    if(tiempo <= 0)
    tiempo = i;  // Esto no me coge que es i
}
```

Ahora aunque las ponga como variables globales esto hara cosas que no quiere, pues el update se llama x veces por frame, e `i` se incrementa en cada update, asi que es posible que tiempo tardara en ser `<= 0` y cuando se asigne dentro del `if` . `tiempo = i;` igual se asigna 100 que 200 que valla usted a saber, pues `i` como se dijo se incrementa cada vez que entre en el update, y usted dice algo asi en la pregunta *...cuando tiempo llegue a 0, que tiempo = 2 , y despues a tiempo = 3...* pero ya vimos que tiempo es posible que nunca pase por 2 ni por tres en la asignacion, *salvo la primera vez que entra en el if o asi*

Pienso que esto es lo que busca:

```
float tiempo;
float i;

void Start(){

    tiempo = 1;
    i=2;
}

void Update(){

    Debug.Log("tiempo" + tiempo);

    tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(tiempo <= 0){

        tiempo = i;  // Esto no me coge que es i
        i++;         
    }
}
```

Variables globales la inicializa en el `Start` por ejemplo y sin restarle importancia a lo que menciono [user3175146](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66214/por-qu%C3%A9-si-pongo-tiempo-i-siendo-i-un-numero-no-me-lo-coge-en-unity/66241#66217) pues es una parte muy importante, fijese que tiene que incrementar el valor de `i++` dentro del `if` osea cuando tiempo sea `<=0` como menciono [user3175146](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66214/por-qu%C3%A9-si-pongo-tiempo-i-siendo-i-un-numero-no-me-lo-coge-en-unity/66241#66217) pues que tiempo sea `== 0` es una loteria, asi cada vez que se cumpla el tiempo este se asignara el valor de `i++`

---

Nota: si quiere que primero incremente `i` antes de asignalo pues cambie el orden dentro del `if`.

Comment: Miraré con detenimiento su pregunta, muchisimas gracias por contestar, le doy +1 porque leyendolo por encima tiene razón, un saludo y en unos dias comentaré mas extendido.